# Using Python and WMI Queries to get a list of running services

Tags: python, windows, wmi, wmi-query

I am attempting to get a list of services that are running on a windows machine with python.

My Code:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()    
wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = ""Running"""
for x in c.query(wql):
    print(x)
```

I am getting an error and I do not understand why. I have a few other wql statements in my script and they seem to be working fine.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/i861470/Desktop/Scripts/test.py", line 79, in <module>
    for x in c.query(wql):
  File "C:\Users\i861470\Desktop\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in query
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Users\i861470\Desktop\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in <listcomp>
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Users\i861470\Desktop\Scripts\venv\lib\site-   packages\win32\com\client\dynamic.py", line 280, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._enum_.__getitem__(index))
  File "C:\Users\i861470\Desktop\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\com\client\util.py", line 41, in __getitem__
    return self.__GetIndex(index)
  File "C:\Users\i861470\Desktop\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\win32\com\client\util.py", line 62, in __GetIndex
    result = self._oleobj_.Next(1)
win32.types.com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = ""Running"""
```

results to an invalid WQL query (checked using `print(wql)`)

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = Running
```

**You need**

```
wql = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = "Running"'
```

which results to a valid WQL query (read [`WHERE` Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054(v=vs.85).aspx) docs)

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = "Running"
```

BTW, you may use string literals, such as `"Running"` or `'Running'`, in a `WHERE` clause. Hence, the following WQL query works as well:

```
wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE State = 'Running'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that same issue on some other statements. I would have never thought to check the wql my printing it.