# How to check if a service is running using WMI in Python?

Tags: python, windows, service, wmi

I am new to Python and coding in general. I am trying to detect if a certain service is running, and if running, to stop it and restart it. If it doesn't exist, throw an exception and exit.

I have the following:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

for service in c.Win32_Service():
    if service.Name == 'genericservice':
        service.StopService()
```

I borrowed that code from another script that we had existing. However, how do I add a conditional statement to check if the service is even running in the first place? And then to exit with an exception if it's not running at all?

Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done using `WQL` in `win32com.client` module.

For example,

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')

if len(WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name like "%s%s"' % ("process_name",'%'))) > 0:
    pass
```

To do so in your way, do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50873223/6505847) using `WQL` to check if that service is indeed running or not.

You can see the [tutorial](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html) if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did like your suggestion, however, my Team Lead is insisting I use WMI only and not Win32 as the former is more standardized, documented, and can do more than the latter can.

Comment: Well, those points you mention for the above are true, however, it also lacks some simple features that you'd expect; or even if it exists i can't seem to locate it in the docs. The only approach to doing via `WMI` is to create a `list`of running services  using the `WQL` approach mentioned in the link above and then in your loop simply check `if service in <List_of_running_services>` . The run time is `o(n)` in avg case so its is not terribly bad.