# Trying to create service searcher

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd, scripting

I'm trying to do a python script that will search for windows services an show them in a listbox with the name, displayname and status, but what I have done so far will only display a zero. In the lower dialog box I can see the 3 outputs but I don't know how to get them into the listbox below it.

```
def search_query(searchbar):
    NameSave=("powershell -command "+'"'+"get-service *"+ searchbar+'* |ft -HideTableHeaders"')
    NameList=subprocess.call(NameSave, shell=True)
    serviceslist.insert(0,NameList)


searchf= tk.Frame(root, 
    bg="#20179a")
searchf.place(relx=0.5, 
    rely= 0.3, 
    relwidth=0.6, 
    relheight=0.075, 
    anchor="n")
searchbar= tk.Entry(searchf,
    font="Helvetica 18 bold",
    justify="center")
searchbar.place(relx=0.4,
    rely=0.5,
    relwidth=0.65, 
    relheight=0.8, 
    anchor="center")
searchbutton=tk.Button(searchf,
    text="Search Service",
    font="Helvetica 16 bold",
    fg="#20179a",
    bd=0,
    command= lambda: search_query(searchbar.get()))
searchbutton.place(relx=0.75,
    rely=0.5,
    relwidth=0.2,
    relheight=0.8, 
    anchor="w")



servicesf=tk.Frame(root,
    bg="#20179a")
servicesf.place(relx=0.05,
    rely=0.4,
    relwidth=0.9,
    relheight=0.45)
serviceslist=tk.Listbox(servicesf, font="Helvetica 18 bold")
serviceslist.place(relx=0.025,
    rely=0.1,
    relwidth=0.95,
    relheight=0.8)
```

[Function  for search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljw6Z.png)

[app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT8Ol.png)

Comment: I don't understand why a Python script is coded for this task. There can be executed in a  [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window `sc query` respectively with full qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe query`. Further I don't understand what should be the benefit to use a Python script which uses one more script interpreter like **PowerShell** for the main task which is run unnecessary using the oldest script interpreter installed by default on Windows - the Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. Why are three script interpreters used for one task?

Comment: See [List local running services on Windows 10 using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52341845/3074564) or [Using Python and WMI queries to get a list of running services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864409/) or other questions and answers found with [\[python\] list windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+list+windows+services).

Comment: I recommend to read carefully and completely the Python documentation of the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html) if you want to capture and display with the Python script the standard output `stdout` of `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell -command "get-service *searchbar* |ft -HideTableHeaders"` with `searchbar` being an unknown string value for us and with `cmd.exe` searching for a file with name `powershell` finding hopefully `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Comment: I suggest also reading carefully and completely also the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used on Windows by `subprocess.run()`, subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.Popen()` to run on `shell=True` the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` as defined by environment variable `ComSpec` with option `/c` and the command line appended as arguments which on having found `powershell.exe` uses also `CreateProcess` to run PowerShell executable.

Comment: In this case with using `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` to get a list of services matching the wildcard pattern with the string value of variable `searchbar` it would be really useful for you to open a command prompt window, run `cmd /?` and read very carefully the output help explaining how the unnecessary used Windows command processor interprets the arguments after option `/c` which is not easy to understand, but must be taken into account in Python code. The usage of three script interpreters with three different syntax rules is really not easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PowerShell native solution to this problem that's just a few lines.

```
Get-Service |Out-GridView -passthru `
   -Title "All Services on $($env:COMPUTERNAME), Select one or more for additional info" |
    Format-List
```

Generates this user interface.

[image]

Then the result can be stored in a variable for later usage, or sent to another command, like in this case `Format-List`

[image]